# Yii 1.1.x CDbHttpSession error: CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, session, pdo, yii

I'm trying to use **CDbHttpSession** in Yii 1.1.x but when I change it in my *main.php* from *CHTTPSession* I get the following error:

> CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: could not find driver

I have PDO drivers successfully installed on my Linux server and I can connect to the database anyway, I only get this error when I try to use CDbHttpSession. 
I also allowed the PDO extensions in my php.ini:

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

I have php5-mysql installed and I restarted the apache2 of course.

I have the following in my main.php:

```
'components' => array(

    ...

    'session' => array(
       'class' => 'CDbHttpSession',
    ),

    ...

    'db' => array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databasename',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'charset' => 'utf8', 
        'tablePrefix' => '',
    ),

    ...

),
```

Thanks in advance for your helping answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify connection ID otherwise Yii tries to use SQLite and you obviously don't have driver for it.

```
'session' => array(
   'class' => 'CDbHttpSession',
   'connectionID' => 'db',
),
```